# Maintaining Background Consistency as Button Count Decreases

Tags: css, flexbox, background

Can the background remain consistent with the buttons as their number reduces from three to two to one?

I want the background to resize to fit the new width when three columns become two and then one, now it just stays fixed with three columns.

I want the background to stay with the buttons.

When the buttons go from 3 to 2 to 1, I want the background to stay attached to the buttons.

I want the background to stay behind the buttons.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/42Lowjt7/4/

From 3
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs8Gn.png)

To 2
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yPQb.png)

To 1
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBra1.png)

I tried using media queries, but I am not sure if that would work in the code.

```
.buttonContainerA {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 476px;
  gap: 10px;
 background: linear-gradient(45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px),
    linear-gradient(-45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #121212;
  padding: 0 8px 0;
}


.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  /*justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;*/
}


.containerB {
  /*display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    position: fixed;
    
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;*/
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  /*display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: auto;*/
  margin: auto;
}



.modal-contentA {
  /*display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;*/
  /* added*/
  /*min-height: 100%;*/
  margin: auto;
  /*justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;*/

}


.buttonContainerA {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 476px;
  gap: 10px;
  /*background: red;*/
 background: linear-gradient(45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px),
    linear-gradient(-45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}

.playButtonA {
  flex-basis: 152px;
  /* width of each button */
  margin: 0;
  /* spacing between buttons */
  cursor: pointer;

}

.btn-primaryA {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0d6efd;
  border-color: #0d6efd;
}

.btnA {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #0d6efd;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}

.btnq {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 0;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: inherit;
  margin: auto;
}

.btnA:hover {
  background-color: #0056b3;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btnA:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0b5ed7;
  border-color: #0a58ca;
  /*box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgb(255 0 0 / 100%)*/
}

.exitB {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*margin: auto;*/
  cursor: pointer;
}

.exitB::before,
.exitB::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exitB::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container ">
  <div class="containerB">
    <div class="modal-contentA">
      <div class="buttonContainerA">
        <button data-destination="#ba" class="playButtonA btn-primaryA btnA">Listening</button>
        <button data-destination="#bb" class="playButtonA btn-primaryA btnA">Live Performance</button>
        <button data-destination="#bc" class="playButtonA btn-primaryA btnA">On Loop</button>
        <button data-destination="#bd" class="playButtonA btn-primaryA btnA">Audio Visual</button>
        <button data-destination="#be" class="playButtonA btn-primaryA btnA">Lyric Video</button>
        <button data-destination="#bf" class="playButtonA btn-primaryA btnA">Music Video</button>
        <button data-destination="#bg" class="playButtonA btn-primaryA btnA">From The Vault</button>
        <button data-destination="#bh" class="playButtonA btn-primaryA btnA">Mystery Box</button>
        <button data-destination="#bi" class="playButtonA btn-primaryA btnA">Cover</button>
        <button data-destination="#bj" class="playButtonA btn-primaryA btnA">Remix</button>
        <button data-destination="#bk" class="playButtonA btn-primaryA btnA">Instrumental</button>
        <button data-destination="#bl" class="playButtonA btn-primaryA btnA">Extended Mix</button>
        <button data-destination="#bm" class="playButtonA btn-primaryA btnA">Duet</button>
        <button data-destination="#bn" class="playButtonA btn-primaryA btnA">Acoustic</button>
        <button data-destination="#bo" class="playButtonA btn-primaryA btnA">Rework</button>
      </div>
      <button class="exitB exit" type="button" title="Exit" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "background remains consistent"? What is the effect you are looking for exactly?

Comment: I want the background to stay with the buttons. When the buttons go from 3 to 2 to 1, I want the background to stay attached to the buttons.

Comment: I want the background to stay behind the buttons.

Comment: adding an image of the expected result could be helpful tho.

Comment: They just want the background resize to fit the new width when three columns become two and then one, now it just stay fixed like with three columns
It something to do with display flex i think, can't figure how to fix yet